# jquery not working with dynamic id on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
$dns_zone = ["domain" => "user", "domain2" => "user2"];
foreach ($dns_zone as $dom => $user){
 echo '
<tr id="tr'.$dom.'">
<td>
    <span>'.$dom.'</span>
    <input type="hidden" id="name'.$dom.'" name="domain" value="'.$dom.'" />
</td>
<td>
    <i class="save " id="sid'.$dom.'" title="Save" ></i>
</td>   
</tr>';

// for Save record
$(document).on("click", ".save", function() {
var id = $(this).attr("id");
id = id.substr(3);
var domain = $("#name"+id).val();
console.log(domain );
});
```

i want to print which domain i select...everything look correct but dont know what the issue...whenever i tried with static value its getting right...problem with dynamic id...but i tried to print 'id' value its working properly...please help me with this...Thank You.

Comment: What is `id = id.substr(3);` for? (`.substr()` is deprecated btw)

Comment: to remove 'sid' from id so can get only domain name as id and i have multiple buttons that's why i used id="sid'.$dom.'".

Comment: That looks overly complicated. You could just use `<i class="save" id="sid'.$dom.'" data-dom="' . $dom . '" title="Save"></i>` and get rid of the hidden inputs. Then use `$(this).data("dom");` to get the domain

Comment: but i have other input box also that's i didn't mention here...i have multiple input box from that i want to fetch data

Comment: Did you try to debug your event handler with a `console.log()`. What does it show?

Comment: undefine getting problem with dynamic id

Comment: Sorry? I mean like `console.log( $(this).attr("id").substr(3) )` or `console.log( $("#name"+id).length )`

Comment: domain name... and that's working properly...

Comment: Your code [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/gk4dbzfx/) as provided and extrapolated.   "*static value is getting right*" - I assume by this you mean it works if you don't use `'.$dom.'` - can you provide the *rendered* html - ie as the browser sees it (open in browser, view source, or open in browser inspect element).   Is it possible you have other inputs with the same ID?   Can you try `$(this).closest("tr").find("input").val()` (maybe add a class to each input if you have more than one per row).

Comment: yes its works if i didn't use '.$dom.'. i search in view page source if there is no other input with same id. thank you for your solution its working for fetch data. but still getting problem with $("#"+id).hide()/show() its won't working with dynamic id is my base concern.

Answer (score 0):

you can improve code quality this way

```
$(".save").click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   id = id.substr(3);
  var domain = $(`#name${id}`).val();
  console.log(domain );
});
```

Comment: Can you explain why `\`#name${id}\`` would work when `"#name" + id` would not work?

Comment: @freedomn-m right not working cause both `#name${id}` and "#name" + id are working same

Comment: Opps probably didnt get your message clearly